# How can I stop my text messages going into my email on my Galaxy S7

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

My text messages are suddenly appearing in my email inbox.  There are several places to turn off sync.  I want my calendar, email etc to syn but not my text messages.  How do I turn that off on a Galaxy S7 model?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into the Email app, select **More**, select **Settings**, select your account under the Accounts heading, scroll down to **Exchange Active Sync settings** and turn off *Sync Messages*.